# React - Same prop name from parent component and context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came up with a mind-boggling situation, which did not (at least yet) cause any problems, but I couldn't find anything by googling.

A theoretical (and unrealistic but illustrative) example of two React Components:

```js
// parent.js
import Child from "./path-to-child";

export function Parent(props) {
  return(
    <Child content="some content" />
  );
}
```

```js
// child.js
import withContext from "./path-to-context";

function Child(props) {
  return(
    <p>
      {props.content}
    </p>
  );
}

export default withContext(Child);
```

So the `Parent` is passing `content` as a `prop` to `Child`. If the context provided by `withContext` HOC also happened to have a property with name `content`, what would happen? Is there an order of precedence or is `content` just the latest value which happens to overwrite the older one or perhaps something else?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but why did you not just test to see what happens on your own? You've already written most of the code.

Comment: I tested quickly before coming to StackOverflow, and in seemed that Parent prop takes precedence over context prop. I'm just not sure if this will always be the case in some weird timing, state change, or overwrite situations, which I did not deem feasible to test in my time frame, or possible to test with my current knowledge of possible caveat situations. But I consequently created a blank React app and that seems to work as mentioned above, Parent prop taking precedence always.